# OnClickListener in fragment doesnt work

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, onclicklistener

I follow the instruction of this https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#HandlingEvents
in my code of the fragment i have this

```
public final class Pag1 extends Fragment {
    Button buton;
    TextView texto;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pag1, container, false);
        View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pag1,container,false);
        buton= (Button)vista.findViewById(R.id.button);
        texto= (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    texto.setText("sadfasdfsad");
                }
            });

        return vista;
    }
}
```

I don´t know why this not working, i see more post and not working for me
If anywants download my project with this https://mega.nz/#!lAwjSIhC!j0nsG4ilwG9VS6_s1zuiY1Qe_0qXsxl0xpiieqVUCw0

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <!-- estas dos lineas arreglan el fallo de que el edit text se
            volviese con el foco al inicio de la aplicacion-->

            <!-- tenia un theme que era el que había puesto en el theme editor pero da problemas y esta mal configurado, lo he
            quitado en el spinner-->

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Elige"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
            <!--android:layout_width="274dp"-->
            <Spinner

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="94dp"
                android:id="@+id/string_array"
                android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:entries="@array/string_array" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="haz"
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Calcular"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_selected"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:width="12dp"
                android:height="25dp"
                android:textSize="25dp" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Info"
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:onClick="info"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_search_url_text_selected"
                android:background="@color/colorAccent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: Did you get any error ?

Comment: Nop, i runs the aplication without errors, when hit the button, nothing happens

Comment: post your xml layout as well

Comment: post it, (I have omitted the FrameLayout)

Comment: Try Cata answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i fix it, In my mainactivity class

(when in android studio you select tabbed activity, created this class that contains customviews and the switch that select what fragment shows, i set the onclicklistener in the fragment, example

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
        if (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pag1, container, false);
            buton= (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            texto= (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

            buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    texto.setText("sadfasdfsad");
                }
            });


            return rootView;
        }
        else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pag2, container, false);
            //
            boton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_button);
            edit = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_editText);
            text = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
            boton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view){

                    String mensaje = edit.getText().toString();
                    text.setText(String.valueOf(mensaje.length()));

                }

            });
            //
            return rootView;
        }
        else{
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
        //



        //
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be because you added the below properties to the LinearLayout that holds the button and maybe the layout is stealing the focus.. try removing those properties and see if that is true.

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: i remove it and not works :( , i put these lines because when i start the app, the editext get focused automaticaly

Comment: Ok then try adding those two properties to the button as well and also clickable="true" :)

Comment: and also make sure you initialize the correct button id

Comment: The id is button, im trying to check the clickable="true", nothing :(

Comment: Ok, could you try setting all those 3 properties on the scrollview and set them to false?

Comment: I put this in scrollview android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:clickable="false", nothing

Comment: Remove all the properties in your layout ,and test whether the button working or not..

Comment: I removing all except textview and button, not working and i dont know why because i follow the steps of developer android and the listener should work

Comment: And you can see the text view being displayed at first with the initial text displayed on it, right?

Comment: Yes, the text is the same and don´t change

Comment: Could you please also set android:clipChildren to true on the scrollview and ListView? I have a hunch that actually the button is cut by the parent layout

Comment: It the same, you can download my project, i upload and watch it 
In case you have forgotten me put something more

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Pag1 extends Fragment {
Button buton;
TextView texto;

public Pag1(){
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vista =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pag1,container,false);
    buton= (Button) vista.findViewById(R.id.button);
    texto= (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                texto.setText("sadfasdfsad");
            }
        });

    return vista;
  }
}
```

Comment: You remove only Comment lines ?¿

Comment: I added an Empty Constructor, Removed final also.

Comment: Added and removed final in public class Pag1 extends Fragment and the button doesn´t work

Comment: can you add a logcat while pressing the button and add the logcat.

Comment: In the logcat appears this: 09-18 20:13:39.350 12357-12357/user.cs I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
09-18 20:13:39.420 12357-12357/user.cs I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
09-18 20:13:40.857 12357-12357/user.cs I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
09-18 20:13:40.952 12357-12357/user.cs I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the code into onStart() method.

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    View v = getView();
    buton= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);

    buton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            texto.setText("sadfasdfsad");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: @ciberelfo Getting any error or there is no effect?

Comment: no effect, now i fix it,  :D i post the solution (onclicklistener in the mainactivity)